# Am I calling my JavaScript Function correctly?

Tags: javascript, function

I am new to Javascript.

I am making my first Adventure Game.

I tested the following code out with an onClick and it worked fine:

```
// JavaScript Document
function changeColour() 
{
    if (document.getElementById('colourTest').style.backgroundColor='yellow') 
    {
        document.getElementById('colourTest').style.backgroundColor='red';
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementByID('colourTest').style.backgroundColor='yellow';
    }
}

var direction;

direction = prompt("Which direction would you like to go ?");

if ( direction == "North" )
{
    changeColour();
}
else
{
    console.log("You can't go in that direction ?");    
}
```

This is the HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="Scarry_Adventure_Game.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Scarry_Adventure_Game.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="colourTest">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the Yellow div to turn red when the user enters the word North, otherwise, the user is told that they can't go in that direction.

I am sure that this is some kind of syntax error :D

Hi, Here is an update:

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="Scarry_Adventure_Game.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" ></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Scarry_Adventure_Game.css" type="text/css">

</head>

<body onload="load();">

        <img id="myimg" alt="My Image" src="images/image1.jpg" />
        <form>
            <input name="heading" type="text" id="which" value="" />    
        </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is JS:

```
   // JavaScript Document

        var img = new Image();
        img.src = "images/image1.jpg";



function whichImage(b)
{
    var image = document.getElementById("myimg");

    if (b == "North")
    {
        image.src = "images/image2.jpg";
    }
    else
    {
        image.src = "images/image1.jpg";
    }
}

function whichDirection (x) 
{
    if (x == "North" || x == "South" || x == "East" || x == "West" ) 
    {
        document.write("You choose to go " + direction);
    }
    else
    {
        document.write("You can't go in that direction");
    }
}

function load()
{
    var direction = document.getElementById('which').value;

    whichDirection(direction);
    whichImage(direction);


}
```

I don't understand why the input direction from the user isn't allowing the image to change to image2.jpg, when the word, North is input by the user.

Can JS actually capture text input from html and then use this with variables in functions?

More over, with this version, the DOM doesn't seem to have loaded, as there is no image to be seen.

Comment: Watch your cases - you have getElementBy **ID** () in one line

Comment: if (document.getElementById('colourTest').style.backgroundColor='yellow'), this is an assignment, use "==" to test equals.

Comment: how are you capturing var direction from the users input?

Comment: If you don't have any specifiy problems, but want to get feedback about your code, http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place to ask

Comment: Thank you guys, I have fixed the errors :D

Comment: The immediate response on here is very much appreciated. An impressive community.

Answer (score 0):

The two errors I see right away (there may be more) are...

```
if (document.getElementById('colourTest').style.backgroundColor='yellow')
```

You're *assigning* instead of *comparing*.  Use `==` for comparison (as you do elsewhere).  And...

```
document.getElementByID('colourTest').style.backgroundColor='yellow';
```

JavaScript is case-sensitive.  The function name should be `getElementById` (as you do elsewhere).

---

In this case there was a logical error and a syntax error.  The latter can often be noticed by looking at the JavaScript console in your browser's debugging tools.  If it tried to execute that line of code, you'd see an error there.  Logical errors, on the other hand, can be trickier to pinpoint.  For those you'll want to familiarize yourself with the debugger in your browser's debugging tools.

You can click on a specific line of JavaScript code to set a "breakpoint" where the execution of code will pause.  Once paused, you can examine the runtime values of your variables, step through the execution line-by-line to check its behavior, etc.  This is how you validate that the code is doing what you expect it to do.

Comment: Hi David, Thank you. I can't find a reason for why my function doesn't work.

Comment: I have this error in the console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null Scarry_Adventure_Game.js:4
changeColour Scarry_Adventure_Game.js:4
(anonymous function)

Comment: @user3683006: Be empirical.  What is the line of code throwing that error?  What are the values when that line executes?  The error means that you're trying to call a `.style` property on a `null` object, which implies that one of your lines of code is not finding the HTML element you intend it to find.

Comment: Thank you Dave. I now see that I need to write code to change linked css. Back to learning JS :S

Comment: I have edited my original question, with an update :D